# Setting HTTP headers in a Play! framework web application

Tags: security, nginx, http-headers, playframework-2.1, owasp

Where can I set security HTTP headers in a Play! framework web application project? I want to set headers like `X-Content-Type-Options` to `nosniff` and `X-Frame-Options` to `DENY`.

I have tried to set these headers in `nginx.conf` file, but it is not working with ZAP tool as ZAP tool is giving an alert that these headers are missing after setting it into this file.

link: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/2524

I have tried the solution in the documentation on [Configuring Security Headers](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SecurityHeaders) but the class `SecurityHeadersFilter` is not present in the package said.

I am using Play! 2.2.1 and Java is used for the controllers.

Comment: what does your nginx configuration look like? `SecurityHeadersFilter` was only [added in Play 2.3](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/commits/7dd0229992cff5f99386cd46abb6dca7c9387fd2/framework/src/play-filters-helpers/src/main/scala/play/filters/headers/SecurityHeadersFilter.scala)

Comment: in nginx.conf file i have added following http { add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; img-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com";
    }  is this right?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best place to do this is `nginx` if you're using it as a reverse proxy for your Play app. Instead of adding the headers in your nginx configuration's `http` section (as per [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444527/play-framework-web-application-how-to-set-http-headers?noredirect=1#comment37897802_24444527)) try adding it in a `server` block.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name *.something.com;

        location /stuff {
                alias ../;

                add_header X-Frame-Options deny; 
                add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"; 
                add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff; 
                add_header X-Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' ssl.google-analytics.com; img-src 'self' ssl.google-analytics.com";
        }
        ...
}
```

results in the headers being correctly set:

[image: Headers correctly set]

Using the [OWASP ZAP tool](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project) I can verify that the header is set correctly. With the `X-Frame-Options` header *not* set:

[image: X-Frame-Options not set]

When the `X-Frame-Options` header *is* set:

[image: X-Frame-Options is set]

Comment: I have added header settings in server block of nginx.conf file but this is also not working properly. Is there any other way to set these headers in play web application? so that it will be applicable for all web pages in the application.

Comment: When you say "not working properly", do you mean the headers are not present at all? (how are you testing that?). What version of nginx you running? Did you restart nginx after making that configuration? Would be helpful if you edited your question with the relevant sections of your `nginx.conf` file as well.

Comment: When I am adding headers to nginx.conf file and I restrted the application using nginx then. I am testing the headers by attacking the application using the ZAP tool, then ZAP tool is showing the alerts that these headers are not set. So how to do with this?

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect testing with ZAP tool. It works for me. If it's still not working for you would you mind sending [something like this](http://i.imgur.com/umxdv1c.png) for further investigation?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to Play 2.3.1 and follow the [configure security headers instructions](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SecurityHeaders) on the playframework site. Note that the upgrade to 2.3.**1** is essential as 2.3.**0** contains a [bug](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2980) which requires a workaround to make it happen.